# @EnableJpaAuditing and LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

After migrating a pure spring v4 app to spring boot 2.1 I have some issues with auditing.

For demonstration purposes I created a little demo app which's setup basically looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateWithJpaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateWithJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@EnableJpaAuditing
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.github.hibernatewithjpa.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "sessionFactory")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, DataSource dataSource) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.github.hibernatewithjpa.domain");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);

        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

I also have a very simple Repository and Entity.

```java
public interface ClientRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Client, Integer> {
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date created;
}
```

The following test shows that the auditing is not applied:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = HibernateWithJpaApplication.class)
public class ClientRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setName("df");

        this.clientRepository.save(client);
        client = this.clientRepository.findById(client.getId()).get();

        assertThat(client.getCreated()).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Also the application uses both JPA and native Hibernate queries. According to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-jpa-hibernate using the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` should be the right approach for our setup. So using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is not really an option.

When debugging I can see that the `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect` can't configure the `AuditingEntityListener` bean as the `BeanConfigurerSupport` misses a `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory`. The handler of the `AuditingEntityListener` is therfore not set and thus auditing is not applied.

I am wondering now if I am doing something wrong or if this is a spring framework or spring boot issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your client contains getCreated() method ?!

Comment: @mohammadreza: yes

Comment: Ok, It is a lombok annotation. You're setting a name for the client but what is your ideal response ?! I mean the createdDate should be null because you're not setting it ?

Comment: Well, that’s exactly the idea of auditing. things get set automatically when saving.